Jaeger not receiving traces
I have deployed jaeger as daemon set on EKS. And it is running fine.
kubectl get all -n observability

NAME                                    READY   STATUS      RESTARTS        AGE
pod/jaeger-agent-2jpqf                  1/1     Running     0               9m52s
pod/jaeger-agent-8qwr4                  1/1     Running     0               9m52s
pod/jaeger-agent-p67w5                  1/1     Running     0               9m52s
pod/jaeger-cassandra-0                  1/1     Running     0               9m52s
pod/jaeger-cassandra-1                  1/1     Running     0               7m50s
pod/jaeger-cassandra-2                  1/1     Running     0               5m48s
pod/jaeger-cassandra-schema-wjxtx       0/1     Completed   1               9m52s
pod/jaeger-collector-5dd98fbb9d-zgjmj   1/1     Running     5 (8m10s ago)   9m52s
pod/jaeger-query-fd77c9577-hb8hr        2/2     Running     5 (8m26s ago)   9m52s

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                         AGE
service/jaeger-agent       ClusterIP   192.168.32.192   <none>        5775/UDP,6831/UDP,6832/UDP,5778/TCP,14271/TCP   9m55s
service/jaeger-cassandra   ClusterIP   None             <none>        7000/TCP,7001/TCP,7199/TCP,9042/TCP,9160/TCP    9m55s
service/jaeger-collector   ClusterIP   192.168.32.32    <none>        14250/TCP,14268/TCP,14269/TCP                   9m55s
service/jaeger-query       ClusterIP   192.168.32.202   <none>        80/TCP,16685/TCP,16687/TCP                      9m55s

NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/jaeger-agent   3         3         3       3            3           <none>          9m54s

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/jaeger-collector   1/1     1            1           9m55s
deployment.apps/jaeger-query       1/1     1            1           9m55s

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/jaeger-collector-5dd98fbb9d   1         1         1       9m56s
replicaset.apps/jaeger-query-fd77c9577        1         1         1       9m56s

NAME                                READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/jaeger-cassandra   3/3     9m56s

NAME                                COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/jaeger-cassandra-schema   1/1           2m12s      9m58s

Now I deployed hotrod app to send traces to my jaeger collector. Below is my manifest yaml.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hotrod
  labels:
    app: hotrod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hotrod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hotrod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hotrod
        image: jaegertracing/example-hotrod:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: OTEL_EXPORTER_JAEGER_ENDPOINT
          value: "http://jaeger-collector:14250" # Update with your Jaeger collector endpoint

But when I open this app and send traces. It does not show up in jaeger.
I am expecting traces to be seen in jaeger. I am exposing pods - jaeger - 16686 and hotrod 8080

When we use hot-rod, we point to port jaeger:4318
Read about OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT
Verify your ports ( https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/next-release/getting-started/ ) :

Example:
https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/blob/f8c1523f64159bf05eedf6aa6ffb09c9402a9932/examples/hotrod/docker-compose.yml#L23
